# Visual Flow - Rich Text inserting unwanted Line Breaks

Tags: visual-flows, line-break, inputrichtext

In my Visualflow all Radio Button Lists, CheckBox Lists, and Multi-Select Checkbox List, give me unwanted line breaks if I convert the label to Rich Text.

It's a normal VisualFlow that is not embedded in a Visualforce Page
(only other example I could find, was of no help since it related to the embedded visualforce page)

[image: VisualFlow_RichText_LineBreak_Example]

Comment: Maybe test enabling the new lightning flow runtime? It doesn't require enabling lightning, and has an issue w return URL that is addressed in summer, but it should be less janky. Flow ui is just bad, I'm amazed it works at all.

Comment: Great!  I've added an answer so we can close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the new lightning flow runtime. It doesn't require enabling lightning, and has an issue w return URL that is addressed in summer17, but it should be less janky.